# Fabric answers SDK crashes on [Fabric with:@[ [Answers class] ]];

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric, xcode10.1, fabric-answers

After upgrading an iOS app to build with Xcode 10.1, I noticed that on devices running old versions of iOS (up to iOS 11.2.1), Fabric Crashlytics for Answers SDK crashes the app.

Crash does not repro on devices running iOS 11.3 or above, or if app is built with Xcode 10.0.

I'm using Answers 1.2.1, with Fabric 1.6.7, using cocoapods.

The crash happens at this line of code:

```
[Fabric with:@[ [Answers class] ]];
```

I will be trying a few things, including upgrading to latest Answers and Fabric SDKs and will update this thread with findings. If you've encountered this before, I'd love to know what worked for you.

Snippet from a sample callstack below, leading to the crash:

```
0   libswiftCore.dylib                   0x00000001056a47d0 patchedBundleForClass(objc_object*, objc_selector*, objc_class*) + 24
1   MySampleApp                          0x0000000100b2e61c FABApplicationIsSignedForDistribution + 52
2   MySampleApp                          0x0000000100b2e5c4 FABApplicationInstallationSource + 24
3   MySampleApp                          0x0000000100b35194 -[FABSettings appSource] + 20
4   MySampleApp                          0x0000000100b355fc -[FABSettings settingsURLForEndpoint:appInstanceIdentifer:appIconHash:] + 496
5   MySampleApp                          0x0000000100b2f798 -[FABSettingsOnboardingManager settingsURL] + 188
6   MySampleApp                          0x0000000100b2e9d4 -[FABSettingsOnboardingManager beginSettingsDownload] + 100
7   MySampleApp                          0x0000000100b31350 -[Fabric onboardAppAndDownloadSettings] + 120
8   MySampleApp                          0x0000000100b30c80 __15+[Fabric with:]_block_invoke + 536
9   libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000183f56a14 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
10  libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000183f5a240 dispatch_once_f$VARIANT$mp + 56
11  MySampleApp                          0x0000000100b30a60 +[Fabric with:] + 176
```

Comment: I'm getting the same thing attempting to initialize Crashlytics. `Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])` yields `+[Fabric isCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10b372cb8`